# A rational "fifth root" of the scalar matrix $2I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

I am working on the following problem from a past exam.

> Find a necessary and sufficient condition for there to exist a square matrix $A$ of order $n$ whose entries are all rational, such that $A^5 = 2I_n$, where $I_n$ stands for the identity matrix of order $n$.

By an argument using determinants, one easily sees that $n\in 5\mathbb Z$ is a necessary condition.  Moreover, if we assume such an $A =: A_5$ exists for $n=5$, then for general $n = 5k$, $A = \bigoplus^kA_5$ is what we want.

Thus the problem boils down to whether there exists a $5\times5$ rational matrix $A$ such that $A^5 = 2I_5$. What I would like to ask is whether such an $A$ exists, and how one can find such $A$ by hand most efficiently.  I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a matrix $A$ that satisfies the polynomial equation $A^5-2A^0=0$. An easy way to obtain this is to take the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of that polynomial $P=X^5-2$; this gives the example of user7530 (and the example by anon also gives this matrix on the most obvious basis). The polynomial$~P$ will be the minimal one satisfied by$~A$ (which may not be surprising here because $X^5-2$ is irreducible over$~\Bbb Q$, but it holds independently of that fact), and also the characteristic polynomial of the matrix$~A$.

Comment: This solution is the most systematic way of attacking the problem!

Answer (score 8):

I would approach the problem by thinking about how $A$ needs to act on basis vectors $e_i$. Since we are applying $A$ five times and there are five basis vectors, we would like $A$ to be a cyclic permutation of the basis vectors, plus an extra scaling by two at some point:
$$e_1 \mapsto e_2 \mapsto e_3 \mapsto e_4 \mapsto e_5 \mapsto 2e_1,$$
for instance.

This gives us the matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}0 & 0& 0& 0 & 2\\1&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\end{array}\right]$$
which has the property you want.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: multiplication by $2^{1/5}$ is a linear map on the dimension-$5$ vector space ${\Bbb Q}[2^{1/5}]$.

Comment: Thank you for your elegant solution.  What intuition is there of behind thinking the vector space $\mathbb Q[2^{1/5}]$?  When are these kinds of spaces useful in general?

Comment: @Pteromys These so-called **number fields** are the basic object of *algebraic number theory*. In this context, it is natural to take an element of a field extension $L/K$ and consider multiplication by it as a linear map of $L$ as a $K$-vector space. The trace and norm are defined that way, and minimal polynomials are related. This hint basically reverses the usual flow which is from number field thinking to vector space thinking.